# Merge inserted values against temp table leaving out null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, auto-versioning

In my process I need to create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger which will accept the new values for the record and create a new version of it, example:

**Note:** Table columns are constantly changing due to business requirements. So if there is a solution that would support `table to table` merge instead of `column to column` that would be awesome.

**ExampleTable**

```
VersionID   |ID     |Value 1    |Value 2
1           |1      |abc        | 123
```

**Example query**

```
INSERT INTO ExampleTable (ID,[Value 1]) VALUES (1,'testabc')
```

**Resulting table:**

```
VersionID   |ID     |Value 1    |Value 2
1           |1      |abc        | 123
2           |1      |testabc    | 123
```

At this moment I have something like this:

```
 -- Get data
 SELECT TOP 1 * INTO #ExistingData FROM dbo.ExampleTableLatestVersionView
 WHERE  ID = @ID

 -- Merge incoming data
 MERGE #ExistingData AS target
 USING inserted as source
 ON (target.ID= source.ID)
 WHEN   MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET target.[Value 1] = source.[Value 1], 
                    target.[Value 2] = source.[Value 2];

-- And afterwards I do a new insert into version table
```

Problem here is that `NULL` values from `inserted` table are overwriting and I end up with this:

```
VersionID   |ID     |Value 1    |Value 2
1           |1      |abc        | 123
2           |1      |testabc    | NULL
```

I was thinking of doing `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` where I could get previous values by referencing `VersionID`, but I want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will use the existing value if provided value is null:

```
 MERGE #ExistingData AS target
 USING inserted as source
 ON (target.ID= source.ID)
 WHEN   MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET target.[Value 1] = ISNULL( source.[Value 1],target.[Value 1]), 
                    target.[Value 2] =  ISNULL( source.[Value 2],target.[Value 2]);
```